# How to make React storybook 'addon-links' work

Tags: reactjs, storybook, storybook-addon-specifications

I am trying to use addon-links. I tried the exact simple button example listed in the documentation, https://www.npmjs.com/package/@storybook/addon-links. LinkTo react component works fine but when I use linkTo function I get "could not navigate to provided story" error. Can someone please help me with this?

```
import React from "react";
import { linkTo } from '@storybook/addon-links';
import LinkTo from '@storybook/addon-links/react';

export default {
  title: 'Button',
};

export const first = () => (
  <button onClick={()=>{
    // debugger;
    linkTo('Button', 'second')
  }}>Go to "Second"</button>
);

export const second = () => (
  <button onClick={linkTo('Button', 'first')}>Go to "First"</button>
);
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code snippet in your question, i.e. the whole render function where you called `linkTo`?

Comment: @Tyblitz Added the code. If I use the LinkTo react component it works fine but linkTo function is throwing the above said error "could not navigate to provided story"

Comment: I'm having the same issue, using the example provided in the addon-links repo.  Did you ever get this working?

Comment: I created a github issue: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/10546

Comment: @Aaron I got it working by having stories in different files.

Answer (score 2):

There is a tricky part with naming. If you provide a `storyName` (since Storybook 6.0; previously it was `story.name`) for your story then you should pas it as a second argument to `linkTo` function call. See more complex example below:

```
import React from "react";
import { linkTo } from '@storybook/addon-links';

export default {
  title: 'Specs - v1/Button',
};

export const firstStory = () => (
  <button onClick={linkTo('Specs - v1/Button', 'Second story name')}>
    Go to "Second"
  </button>

);

export const second = () => (
  <button onClick={linkTo('Specs - v1/Button', 'firstStory')}>
    Go to "First"
  </button>
);
second.storyName = 'Second story name';
```

Also pay attention that 'linkTo' call returns a new function. So you should not wrap it with anonymous function as you did it in example:

```
// Wrong
<button onClick={() => linkTo('Button', 'second')}>
  Go to "Second"
</button>

// Correct
<button onClick={linkTo('Button', 'second')}>
  Go to "Second"
</button>
```